# how to pass and get Enums as parameters in angular routing?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 15.
the models I defined as below:

```js
export enum CustomerTypes {
  Real,
  Legal,
}

export class Customer {
  public customerId?: number;
  public customerType?: CustomerTypes;
  public customerName?: string;

}
```

in the main-page.component.html, I pass the customerType as a parameter to customers.component.ts.

**main-page.component.html:**

```html
<mat-list-item  routerLink="customers" routerLinkActive="activeLink"> 'customers list' </mat-list-item>
```

the content of coustomers.component.ts and its routing-module:

```js
**//customers-routing.module.ts:**
const routes: Routes =[
  { path: '', component: CustomersComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'customersList/:type',
        component: CustomersListComponent
      },
      
      // rest of code ...
      
      
**//customers.component.ts:**
    
      customerType = [CustomerTypes.Real, CustomerTypes.Legal];
```

```html
**//customers.component.html:**
<a mat-tab-link
     [routerLink]="['customersList', customerType[0]]"
     routerLinkActive="activeLink"
     [active]="activeLi == 'real'"> {{ 'real customer' }} </a>
<a mat-tab-link
     [routerLink]="['customersList', customerType[1]]"
     routerLinkActive="activeLink"
     [active]="activeLi == 'legal'"> {{ 'legal customer' }} </a>
     
     // rest of code ...
```

so far, the customer component replaces the customrList component with its `<route-outlet>` to list the customers by customerType. in the customerList.component.ts, getting all customers is successfully, but creating a new customer by its customertype property rises an error in side of server. because, the custometType value which got from route as parameter has not CustomerType type!
the content of customerList.componet.ts for getting customertype as a parameter from the route and getting all customers by their type as well as creating new customer are following:

```js
**//customerList.component.ts**
 
 customertype!: CustomeType;
 newCustomer!: Customer
 //getting all customers by their type is done successfully
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customersForList$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: Params) => {
        return  this.customersService.getCustomersForListByType(this.customerType = params['get']('type'))
        }));
 }     
 
 
 **//creating new customer** 
 addNewCustomer(): void{
        this.newCustomer = new Customer();
        this.newCustomer.customerName = 'xyz';
        this.newCustomer.custometType = this.customerType;
        console.log(`customerType: ${this.customerType}`); //customerType: 0
        this.customersService.addCustomer(this.newCustomer); // error 500 from server...
        //rest of code ...
 }
```

I dont know whats the type of customerType. it seems that its type is not CustomerType (Enum). even, I tried to use switch statement to set the newCustomer.customerType with correct value:

```js
this.newCustomer.name = 'xyz';
        switch(this.customerType){
           case 0: this.newCustomer.customerType = CustomerType.real; break;
           case 1: this.newCustomer.customerType = CustomerType.legal; break;
        }
        this.customersService.addCustomer(this.newCustomer);
```

but. unfortunately, it seems that the customerType value is not 0 or 1 at all and the switch does not work. It is interesting that the parameter sent to the service to get all customers based on thier type works perfectly. In other words, the parameter sent to the service is of Enum type. See the content of the service:

```js
// ===== works well ....
getCustomersForListByType(type: CustomerTypes): Observable<Customer[]> {

   return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getCustomersByType/' + type);.}
   
// has error 500 !!!!!!
  addCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http.post<Customer>(this.baseUrl + '/addCustomer', customer);}
```

how can I have the customerType value correctly from the route to add a new customer?

Comment: Could you provide what is the error on the server side?

Comment: We wrote the controller action code to save the entity (using ef commands in Asp.net core 5) in the database and, if it can't do it, returns the code 500. that this is due to an invalid value is in customerType property . When i set manually value of customerType to CustomerType.Real at client-side (angular), The action works fine.

Comment: In javascript variables do not have types, values dose. So when you get the val from route it is probably a string. My gues is to use cast: this.customerType = params['get']('type') as CustomerTypes. If it is correct I would post this as an answer.